# simple nested "If else" statement

Tags: c++

No errors when compiling...But I get nothing for my output. I know this is a very noobish attempt at coding... I have mostly been working with numbers...the string stuff kind of confuses me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char chr;

int main()
{
    string name;
    string artist;
    string Taylor;
    string Alan;
    string general;
    string box;
    string seating;

    cout << "Enter your name followed by the return key" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Taylor for Taylor Swift tickets or Alan for Alan Jacskon seats, followed" << endl << "by the enter key" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter box for box seating or general for general seating, followed by the enter key" << endl << endl;
    cin >> artist;
    cin >> seating;

    if ( artist + seating == Taylor + general )
        cout <<  name << ", Your ticket will cost $60" << endl;
    else if ( artist + seating == Taylor + box )
        cout <<  name << ", Your ticket will cost $100" << endl;
    else if ( artist + seating == Alan + box )
        cout <<  name << ", Your ticket will cost $75" << endl;
    else if ( artist + seating == Alan + general )
        cout <<  name << ", Your ticket will cost $50" << endl;

    cin >> chr;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Taylor`, `Alan`, `general` and `box` are in your logic literal values, not variables... your code to work should become

```
string Taylor = "Taylor";
string Alan = "Alan";
string general = "general";
string box = "box";
```

In C++ you cannot unfortunately just write

```
if ( artist + seating == "Taylor" + "general" )
```

for reasons that are too complex to explain here, you could instead get rid of the variables for those values and use

```
if ( artist + seating == "Taylorgeneral" )
```

BTW: I'm not sure if C++ is a good choice for learning programming. A better fit for this job would be in my opinion [Python](http://www.python.org) (or coding in assembler for a simple CPU like 6502, but that's another completely different approach).

Answer (score 1):

The strings `Taylor, Alan, general, box` are never initialized. Comparing them makes no sense.
What you probably want is:

```
string Taylor = "Taylor";
string Alan = "Alan";
string general = "general";
string box = "box";
```

Comment: could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed your if statements to this format, they worked.

> if (( artist  == "Taylor") && (seating == "general"))

```
  cout <<  name << ", Your ticket will cost $60" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized string Taylor; string Alan; string general; string box; so they are all ='\0' ,it do not match any case ,so you get no output.
what,s more when you use cin for input ,it will neglect '\n' ,' ', you can also use cin.getline(string a) for the input